# Import a .step filein unity with C# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

**I would like to import a file ".step" to use it with unity 2018.3.1f1 but I don't know how to do it
I didn't found any topic.
Any one could help me please ?**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

.step is a cad file, right? This isn't supported by unity out of the box. You may need to buy an asset store plugin to open cad files, or roll your own importer. You would need to read up on the file format and build a new mesh based on interpretation of the file format.

Documentation on building a mesh from scratch: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GeneratingMeshGeometryProcedurally.html